# В результирующем наборе отсутствует текущая строка

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Есть БД ms SQL. Таблица `drivers`. Подключение из запись идёт отлично. Но `SELECT` не работает. И не могу понять почему. Вызываю ниже описанную функцию

```
public Integer getUser(String login /*сюда передаётся строка со значением "test"*/){
        Integer id = null;
        try {
            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM drivers WHERE login='"+login+"' ");
            System.out.println("rownums-->"+rs.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(2));
            id = rs.getInt("id");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MysqlClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return id;
    }
```

Получаю ошибку

```
"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: В результирующем наборе отсутствует текущая строка."
```

В то время как в БД этот же запрос (`SELECT * FROM drivers WHERE login='test'`) отбирает данные
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Помогло  изменение кода ` while(rs.next()){
                id = rs.getInt("id");
            }` , но зачем цикл если результат всегда один будет, так как поле login с уникальным индексом?

Comment: видимо, потому что ответ БД по умолчанию представляет из себя множество, пусть даже из одного элемента. БД (а уж тем более принимающий код) в душе не представляет, уникальный будет результат или нет. И для получения данных сначала надо зарпосить хотя бы первый результат.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете не использовать цикл, но вызвать `rs.next()` обязательно. Чтобы передвинуть курсор на первую запись и узнать, есть ли хоть одна строка. Например, так:

```
if(!rs.next())
    throw new SQLException("Почему-то нету логина "+login);
id = rs.getInt("id");
```

Если вы не хотите ругаться в случае несуществующего пользователя, а хотите возвращать `null`, то так:

```
if(rs.next())
    id = rs.getInt("id");
```